# 'order by' in advanced recursive query with join on Postgres

Tags: postgresql, recursion

I have problem with query, which based on recursive clause:

I have two tables: menu (menu categories) and menu_items (items in those categories). Those tables are join: each category can have some items. The order in view the menu on site is based on column: 'menuitem_next'. The join column is menuitem_parent. And now, I want to view the menu, so I use query:

```
select * from menu m left join 
    (With RECURSIVE submenu AS 
        (Select * from menu_item where menuitem_name not in 
            (select menuitem_next from menu_item where menuitem_next is not null) 
        Union all 
            SELECT mi.* FROM menu_item AS mi JOIN submenu AS sm ON 
                (mi.menuitem_name=sm.menuitem_next)
        ) 
        SELECT * FROM submenu 
     )r 
on m.menu_id=r.menuitem_parent order by m, r
```

And order in result query is not properly. Categories is sorted by id, and menuitems are sorted properly with 'menuitem_next' column. Can anyone help me in modify this query or in writing new ?

I'm sorry for my not good english.

Regards

Comment: The usual shortcomings: Postgres version, table definition, test data, expected result (which would help to understand your requirements). Please amend.

Comment: What have you meant by `ORDER m, r`? What is `m` and what is `r`? It looks like all your columns have meaningful names. Are you by any chance trying to put table aliases in there?

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is an `ORDER BY` in the *outer* query, there is no specific ordering defined for the query.

Your query construction is very weird, so I've restructured it to keep the CTE as the outer query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE 
submenu AS (
    SELECT * from menu_item 
    WHERE menuitem_name NOT IN (
        SELECT menuitem_next
        FROM menu_item 
        WHERE menuitem_next IS NOT NULL
    ) 
    UNION ALL
     SELECT mi.* FROM menu_item AS mi 
     INNER JOIN submenu AS sm
     ON (mi.menuitem_name=sm.menuitem_next)
)
SELECT * 
FROM menu m
LEFT OUTER JOIN submenu sm
ON m.menu_id = sm.menuitem_parent
ORDER BY m, sm;
```

At this point it becomes clear that your `ORDER BY` clause is on the *whole tuple* from `submenu`, not a field from it. Perhaps you meant to order by a specific field?

You don't specify field-lists in your `SELECT`s so I can't actually tell what the fields are. This isn't very good practice since it'll cause unexpected results if you add columns to the tables later; you should always list columns explicitly rather than write `SELECT *`.

Comment: Thank you for response. I have done it in java code. I mean I made simple query which join two mentioned tables, and I have ordered them using java code (I made something like linked, one-direction, list). Regards